# Создание фонового вью

Tags: objective-c, ios7, io, ios8

Необходимо создать `UIView`, для блокировки действий пользователя на экране, вью должно закрывать весь экран включая `NavigationBar`, Можно создать через `Window` но хотелось бы какой-нибудь более простой способ, может есть библиотека под это дело ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну куда уже проще. просто сделать полупрозрачный вью по размеру экрана и положить на вью текущего ViewController

Comment: закрывать весь экран включая NavigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте `view`, сделайте его черным и поставьте прозрачность. Далее добавьте это `view` на `window`.

```
UIView *myView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
myView.alpha = 0.2f;
UIWindow *currentWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[currentWindow addSubview:myView];
```

ИМХО ради данного вью нет смысла искать и прикручивать библиотеку.